# Error handling: Display a blank input page if database row does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an account settings page for a user to submit a video and give it a title to display on his/her profile. Once submitted, the video gets tied to the AccountInfoID and creates a row in my dbo.Spotlight database:

[image]

[image]

The only way to get that Video spotlight page to show above is if you manually enter a youtube video into the database that's tied to the accountinfoID since the page can then pull and display the information to fill the input boxes. If no row exists for the user, an error is thrown: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I was wondering what error handling I can do to check to see if a row in the spotlight database is found that has the user's account and if not, still display the page with blank input boxes. **I commented above the line that I know causes the error.**

```
public ActionResult CreatorSpotlight()
{
    var model = new AccountSpotlightViewModel();
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var accountInfo = EntityDataAccess.GetAccountInfoByUserID(userID);
    if(accountInfo != null && accountInfo.CreatorFL == false)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Spotlight", "Account");
    }
    //the next line is what causes the page to throw an error since it may not find the userid in the spotlight database
    model.Spotlight = EntityDataAccess.GetSpotlightByUserID(userID);
    model.Spotlight.AccountInfo = null;
    return View(model);
}
```

I submit through ajax:

```
    function submitSpotlight()
    {

        var spotlight = new Object();
        spotlight.AlbumName = $("#youtube-title").val();
        spotlight.YouTubeURL = $("#video-spot-1").val();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Account/SubmitSpotlight/")",
            data: JSON.stringify(spotlight),
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data == true)
                {
                    location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                //TODO: Indicate Error
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the JSON encode that's tied to the ajax request that stores the values into the dbo.spotlight

```
public JsonResult SubmitSpotlight(Spotlight spotlight)
        {
            try
            {
                var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                spotlight.AccountInfoID = EntityDataAccess.GetAccountInfoByUserID(userID).AccountInfoID;
                if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(spotlight.YouTubeURL))
                {
                    var videoKey = spotlight.YouTubeURL.Replace("https://youtu.be/", "");
                    spotlight.EmbedYouTubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoKey + "?showinfo=0";
                    spotlight.ThumbnailURL = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoKey + "/maxresdefault.jpg";
                }
                var _spotlight = EntityDataAccess.GetSpotlightByUserID(userID);
                if(_spotlight == null)
                {
                    EntityDataAccess.InsertSpotlight(spotlight);
                }
                else
                {
                    spotlight.SpotlightID = _spotlight.SpotlightID;
                    EntityDataAccess.UpdateSpotlight(spotlight);
                }
                return Json(true);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex);
            }
        }
```

**Update added GetspotlightbyuserID**

```
  public static Spotlight GetSpotlightByUserID(string userID)
    {
        using(var Context = GetContext())
        {
            return Context.Spotlights.Include("AccountInfo").Where(x => x.AccountInfo.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What `GetSpotlightByUserID` method content looks like? If no rows exist you can use custom message handling.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto added that for you in the original question. Could you show me what you mean by custom message handling? I'm still new to c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could come from the returned value here

```
model.Spotlight = EntityDataAccess.GetSpotlightByUserID(userID);
```

Check the value of model.Spotlight for null before setting model.Spotlight.AccountInfo to null as follows;

```
model.Spotlight = EntityDataAccess.GetSpotlightByUserID(userID);
if (model.Spotlight!=null){
    model.Spotlight.AccountInfo = null;
}   

return View(model);
```